# SSMS 19.2 Authentication Failure: Azure SQL DB AAD - Service Principal Auth vs Entra ID - Service Principal Auth

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to connect from SSMS to an Azure SQL DB with a service principal. I have added the service principal user to the database and granted `db_datareader` permission.

Connecting with SSMS version 19.1.56.0 and `Azure Active Directory - Service Principal` authentication works successfully, using the App Id as the username, and the client secret as the password.

[image: screenshot of successful connection to the database using SP auth with SSMS v19.1]

When trying to connect using the same method in SSMS 19.2, the connection fails with `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.`

[image: screenshot of failed connection in ssms 19.2]

The only difference I can see is the `Authentication` method is changed from `Azure Active Directory - Service Principal` to `Microsoft Entra Service Principal`.

Why does this no longer work?

Comment: Have you tried updating to the latest version of SSMS? (Though it shouldn't make any difference, it's just the name that has changed.)

Comment: We're up to SSMS 19.3.4 now. Does that work?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning same issue after update unfortunately.

Comment: also cc: @ThomA

Answer (score -1):

> SSMS 19.2 Authentication Failure: Azure SQL DB AAD - Service Principal Auth vs Entra ID - Service Principal Auth

Faced the similar issue and the cause of issue is you have created user in the particular database but when you are trying to login directly its default logging in master database.

When connecting to database through SSMS go to **Connection Properties >> specify the database name >> Connect**.

[image]

Comment: I am specifying the database name in the connection properties in both scenarios.

Comment: have you checked your credentials are correct secret is not expired?

Comment: Yes the credentials are correct - I use exactly the same username (Service Principal App ID) and password (Client Secret) when connecting with both versions of SSMS.